# How to design a table that can either reference another table or be a custom entry

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have a website with many different brick-and-mortar businesses as clients.

I need a table that holds "closed" dates for each business.

My initial design is to have all of the usual US Federal holidays listed in a table, which I then reference via foreign key from the master table of closed days.  That makes it very easy to put checkboxes in the UI so they can easily check off the federal holidays.

But I also need to support custom closing dates.

My intial design is as follows:

```
+-------------+
| close_dts   |     +-------------+     +--------------+
--------------+     | holidays    |     | holiday_tags |
| id          |     +-------------+     +--------------+
| holiday_id  | --> | id          |     | id           |
| custom_date |     | holiday_tag | --> | tag          |
+-------------+     | date        |     | name         |
                    +-------------+     +--------------+
```

Where

- holiday_tags is just a list of the major holidays that happen every year.
- holidays is the actual dates for each holiday, year after year
- close_dts either has a link to the holidays table OR a custom date.

What I'm basically asking here is how to handle the situation in which I would normally
like to link to another table of standard items, but also occasionally define a custom
item that doesn't link to anything.

This is MySQL, if it matters.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design is okay. You could add a constraint so that always only either holiday_id or custom_date is filled.

You can, however, make your model even simpler:

```
+----------------+
| close_dts      |     +--------------+
-----------------+     | holiday_tags |
| id             |     +--------------+
| holiday_tag_id | --> | id           |
| close_date     |     | tag          |
+----------------+     | name         |
                       +--------------+
```

With holiday_tag_id being nullable.

Comment: Good point on the constraint.  Can you give me a hint about what something like that would look like?  I didn't know you could do exclusive-or constraints.

Comment: True, MySQL doesn't support check constraints. But you can check data in before insert/update triggers and make them raise an error on invalid data. However, with my suggested model you wouldn't need them. You would simply store all close dates and tag some of them as holidays, that's all. And the access is easy: you'd always look for the date in close_dts. That means simpler queries.